# $.ajax serialize() does not pass data to php file

Tags: ajax

What is incorrect in the code? Can not pass data to _autosave.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        autosave();
    });

    function autosave() {
        var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000);
        var inputValues= $('.input_form').serialize();
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "_autosave.php",
            data: inputValues,
    } )
    .done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
    ...
```

Input is this

```
 <form id="input_form" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" 
       method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input">
```

_autosave.php is this

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
echo $input .' input<br>';
```

If I enter some value in input, get `input<br>` instead of entered value

**Update**
If for someone may be necessary here is working code

```
$.post("_autosave.php", $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#load').html(data);
    $('#is_row_changed1').val(0)
});
```

Comment: Try to open firebug and check if you send something from your borwser. You can also check sources of your page and action attribute of form

Comment: I see it now! You send your form on document ready instead of click event of some button. Where is your submit button ?

Comment: code executes on var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000); After every 5 seconds I see input<br>. That means that value of <input type="text" name="input" id="input"> is not passed to _autosave.php. Suppose some mistake in ajax code, but do not understand where

Comment: Code executes every 5000 milliseconds since page loads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing comma here resulting in invalid javascript:

```
data: inputValues,
```

Here's how you could fix (and improve your current code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(autosave);

    function autosave() {
        window.setTimeout(autosave, 5000);
        var inputValues = $('.input_form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "_autosave.php",
            data: inputValues
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

or if you prefer a shorthand:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(autosave);

    function autosave() {
        window.setTimeout(autosave, 5000);
        var inputValues = $('.input_form').serialize();
        $.post("_autosave.php", inputValues, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `serializeArray()` instead?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(autosave);

function autosave() {
    window.setTimeout(autosave, 5000);
    $.post("_autosave.php", $('.input_form').serializeArray(),
     function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
</script>
```